# Wkhtmltopdf multiple switches not working

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to use wkhtmltopdf to create a pdf out of a webpage I made which has a specific width and hieght. I get a few blank pages, none of which are my xhtml.

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --margin-bottom 0px --margin-left 0px --margin-right 0px --margin-top 0px --page-width 200px --page-height 500px C:\Users\user\page.xhtml C:\Users\user\finally.pdf
```

What am I doing wrong? The documentation did not help me find my error.

Comment: Does it work without all the margin options ?

Comment: @kebs No, it does not. However, Instead of many blank pages, I only get one blank page without the margin options.

Comment: You probably have something specific on your document, maybe ? Because it should indeed work out of the box.

Comment: @kebs Instead, is there any way to resize the contents of the pdf to fit 100% of the width? It now only fits the xhtml's specified dimensions.

Comment: You mean printing on a specific dimension page ? Yes, it supports that. But first step is getting something out, at present you only have a blank page. Or do you ?

Comment: Without any other options, I do get my output. How would I print to a specific dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you cannot specify a page dimension as pixel units. This is ok for margins, but not for page. Indeed, a pdf file was designed at the beginning to be printed, so it needs to have *physical* dimensions. Pixel values mean nothing physically, unless you give along a [dpi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) (or ppi) value.

So the correct command line would be something like:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --margin-bottom 0px --margin-left 0px --margin-right 0px --margin-top 0px --page-width 4cm --page-height 20cm input.html output.pdf
```

Just adjust the values to your needs, according to the dpi resolution you need.

This is not explicitly stated in [the manual](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt), but I confirm that you get an empty page with page dimensions expressed in pixels.